# How to get links using selenium and scrape using beautifulsoup?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to collect articles from this particular website. I was using Beautifulsoup only earlier but it was not grabbing the links. So I tried to use selenium. Now I tried to write this code. This is giving output 'None'. I have never used selenium before, so I don't have much idea about it. What should I change in this code to make it work and give the desired results?

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

base = 'https://metro.co.uk'
url = 'https://metro.co.uk/search/#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=cybersecurity&gsc.sort=date&gsc.page=7'

browser = webdriver.Safari(executable_path='/usr/bin/safaridriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
browser.get(url)

link = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('gs-title')
for links in link:
    links.get_attribute('href')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
    date = soup.find('span', {'class': 'post-date'})
    title = soup.find('h1', {'class':'headline'})
    content = soup.find('div',{'class':'article-body'})
    print(date)
    print(title)
    print(content)

    time.sleep(3)
browser.close()
```

I want to collect the date, title, and content from all the articles on this page and other pages also like page no 7 to 18.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Selenium to get the anchors, I tried to extract the page source first with the help of Selenium and then used Beautiful Soup on it.

So, to put it in perspective:

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

base = 'https://metro.co.uk'
url = 'https://metro.co.uk/search/#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=cybersecurity&gsc.sort=date&gsc.page=7'

browser = webdriver.Safari(executable_path='/usr/bin/safaridriver')
#wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10) #Not actually required
browser.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser') #Get the Page Source
anchors = soup.find_all("a", class_ = "gs-title") #Now find the anchors

for anchor in anchors:
    browser.get(anchor['href']) #Connect to the News Link, and extract it's Page Source
    sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
    date = sub_soup.find('span', {'class': 'post-date'})
    title = sub_soup.find('h1', {'class':'post-title'}) #Note that the class attribute for the heading is 'post-title' and not 'headline'
    content = sub_soup.find('div',{'class':'article-body'})
    print([date.string, title.string, content.string])

    #time.sleep(3) #Even this I don't believe is required
browser.close()
```

With this modification, I believe you can get your required contents.

Comment: Thanks, It is working. But Why it is printing or giving each article twice?

Comment: If you see the page source for the [url](https://metro.co.uk/search/#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=cybersecurity&gsc.sort=date&gsc.page=7), then you'll find that there are 2 places within every result area where `a` tag with `class="gs-title"` is placed. Both of them are `div` in nature, but they differ in their class. One has `class = "gsc-thumbnail-inside"` & the other has `class = "gs-title gsc-table-cell-thumbnail gsc-thumbnail-left"`. I believe this can be easily resolved by checking at the beginning of every loop that whether current anchor value is similar to previous anchor value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same API as page uses. Alter parameters to get all pages of results

```
import requests
import json
import re

r = requests.get('https://cse.google.com/cse/element/v1?rsz=filtered_cse&num=10&hl=en&source=gcsc&gss=.uk&start=60&cselibv=5d7bf4891789cfae&cx=012545676297898659090:wk87ya_pczq&q=cybersecurity&safe=off&cse_tok=AKaTTZjKIBzl-5fANH8dQ8f78cv2:1560500563340&filter=0&sort=date&exp=csqr,4229469&callback=google.search.cse.api3732')
p = re.compile(r'api3732\((.*)\);', re.DOTALL)
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
links = [item['clicktrackUrl'] for item in data['results']]
print(links)
```